# Exact solution of an simple Meijer-G function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to simplify the following Meijer-G funtion
\begin{equation}
G^{2,2}_{2,2}\Bigl({}^{0,\, 1-m}_{0,\,0} |x \Bigr)
\end{equation}
But the Matlab(MuPAD) and WolframAlpha give me different results, which are not equivalent (The second terms of both answers are equivalent, but not the first terms.).

Does anyone, who is familar with both softwares, know what leads to the difference and which software gives the correct result. Thanks in advance.

Results from Matlab(MuPAD):

[image]

Results from WolframAlpha:

[image]

Note that the hypergeometric functions in the two answers are related as follows: ${}_{2}F_{1}(a, b; c; x)={}_{2}\widetilde{F}_{1}(a, b; c; x) \times \Gamma(c)$

Comment: Consider using http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.ii .

Comment: @Johannes . Thanks a lot. Now both equations are equivalent.:)